# Fail to start Apache Directory Server - Error 04450

Tags: ldap, apacheds

While I was trying to start ApacheDS 1.5.7 on windows platform, An Error 04450 occurs and the apacheds-rolling.log contains:

```
[21:07:27] ERROR [org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.entry.DefaultServerAttribute] - ERR_04450 The value {0} is incorrect, it hasnt been added
[21:07:27] ERROR [org.apache.directory.server.Service] - Cannot start the server : reuseAddress can't be set while the acceptor is bound.
```

How can i fix this problem? Anybody could help me? many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The warning log message is a bit misleading, actually this is not a serious issue, the server should be running despite of this warning, this has been fixed a while back in the latest trunk code (which will be released as 2.0 instead of 1.5.8).

Comment: Thanks! I got this too... I thought it had something to do with my SSL certificate configuration

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://markmail.org/thread/vvheqbltht3tsdwf#query%3a+page:1+mid%3anygb5l75l6njzxr3+state%3aresults), the dc=example,dc=org context entry is not created by default anymore but no one has updated the documentation to reflect this.  I installed 1.5.7 and it looks to me like the partition was created fine, but I'm getting the same error as described above.  I suggest installing an older version.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd error message suggests that the port is already in use. Is there a chance that you already had another ApacheDS process running, or that another program is using the ports?

This isn't a domain controller perchance, is it? If so, the default LDAP ports 389 & 636 are already in use for Active Directory, so you'll need to choose another. However, I believe the defaults for ApacheDS are 10389 (LDAP) and 10636 (LDAPS), in which case they would typically be open on a Windows box.

You can check for processes on the ports with the `netstat -abn` command, and look through the list for the process listening on port 10389 or whichever custom port you chose.

Comment: Hi ewall, Both the port 10389 and 10636 are available. Do you know what does the first error message mean? Is there any configuration issue?

Comment: The confusing part is that the error shows '{0}' instead of the configuration parameter. There were some bugs in earlier versions that caused this, but they should be fixed in v1.5.7 (which I assume you are using). So, offhand, I don't know what else it could be, but I'll think about it...

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version. Thank you all the same.